# Whenever I restart my ubuntu system (Vbox) and start my hadoop , my name node is not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

Whenever I restart my ubuntu system (Vbox) and start my Hadoop, my name node is not working.

To resolve this I have to always the folders of **namenode** and **datanode** and format Hadoop every time I restart my system.

Since 2 days am trying to resolve the issue but its not working. I tried to give the permissions 777 again to the namenode and datanode folders, also I tried changing the paths for the same.

My error is

> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /blade/Downloads/Hadoop/data/datanode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just shutdown the VM. You need to cleanly stop the datanode and namenode processes in that order, otherwise there's a potential for a corrupted HDFS, causing you to need to reformat, assuming that you don't have a backup system

I'd also suggest putting Hadoop data for a VM in its own VM drive and mount, not a shared host folder under Downloads